# How the use threads in groovy to iterate 0.4 million records

Tags: java, groovy

```
// this query returns 0.45 million records and stored in the list.
List<Employee> empList=result.getQuery(query);
```

Iterating employee list and setting property and finally calling service method to save employee object.
using sequential process method its taking lot of time because of the volume of records so I want to use threads .I am new to groovy and implemented only simple examples.

How to use threads for below logic using groovy?

```
for (Employee employee : empList) {
    employee.setQuantity(8);
    employeeService.save(employee);
}
```

Comment: `UPDATE employee SET quantity=8 WHERE ...` might be faster by many magnitudes, but of course depends on your "database" and what other things `save` does (e.g. audit-logging).

Comment: Looping a half million `Employee` objects to update a property and write back to a H2 database locally on my Mac takes under 4 seconds. And using SQL as suggested in [comment by cfrick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65335779/how-the-use-threads-in-groovy-to-iterate-0-4-million-records/65390302#comment115512240_65335779) would be even faster. So the context of your Question does not make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are frameworks to do this (gpars comes to mind) and also the java executors framework is a better abstraction than straight up threads, but if we want to keep things really primitive, you can split your list up in batches and run each batch on a separate thread by using something like:

```
def employeeService = new EmployeeService()

def empList   = (1..400000).collect { new Employee() }
def batchSize = 10000

def workerThreads = empList.collate(batchSize).withIndex().collect { List<Employee> batch, int index ->
  Thread.start("worker-thread-${index}") { 
    println "worker ${index} starting"
    batch.each { Employee e -> 
      e.quantity = 8
      employeeService.save(e)
    }
    println "worker ${index} completed"
  }
}

println "main thread waiting for workers to finish"
workerThreads*.join()
println "workers finished, exiting..."

class Employee { 
  int quantity
}

class EmployeeService { 
  def save(Employee e) {
    Thread.sleep(1)
  }
}
```

which, when run, prints:

```
─➤ groovy solution.groovy
worker 7 starting
worker 11 starting
worker 5 starting
worker 13 starting
worker 17 starting
worker 16 starting
worker 2 starting
worker 18 starting
worker 6 starting
worker 15 starting
worker 12 starting
worker 14 starting
worker 1 starting
worker 4 starting
worker 10 starting
worker 8 starting
worker 9 starting
worker 3 starting
worker 0 starting
worker 20 starting
worker 21 starting
worker 19 starting
worker 22 starting
worker 24 starting
worker 23 starting
worker 25 starting
worker 26 starting
worker 27 starting
worker 28 starting
worker 29 starting
worker 30 starting
worker 31 starting
worker 32 starting
worker 33 starting
worker 34 starting
worker 35 starting
worker 36 starting
worker 37 starting
worker 38 starting
worker 39 starting
main thread waiting for workers to finish
worker 0 completed
worker 16 completed
worker 20 completed
worker 1 completed
worker 3 completed
worker 14 completed
worker 7 completed
worker 12 completed
worker 24 completed
worker 10 completed
worker 6 completed
worker 19 completed
worker 33 completed
worker 27 completed
worker 28 completed
worker 35 completed
worker 17 completed
worker 25 completed
worker 38 completed
worker 4 completed
worker 8 completed
worker 13 completed
worker 9 completed
worker 39 completed
worker 15 completed
worker 36 completed
worker 37 completed
worker 18 completed
worker 30 completed
worker 23 completed
worker 11 completed
worker 32 completed
worker 2 completed
worker 29 completed
worker 26 completed
worker 5 completed
worker 22 completed
worker 31 completed
worker 21 completed
worker 34 completed
workers finished, exiting...
```

`List.collate` splits the list of employees into chunks (`List<Employee>`) of size `batchSize`. `withIndex` is just there so that each batch also gets an index (i.e. just a number 0, 1, 2, 3...) for debuggability and tracing.

As we are starting threads, we need to wait for them to complete, the `workerThreads*.join()` is essentially doing the same thing as:

```
workerThreds.each { t -> t.join() }
```

but using a more concise syntax and `Thread.join()` is a java construct for waiting for a thread to complete.

Comment: Most correct. Thanks for the sanity check, answer updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

## Use the database, not Java

As [commented by cfrick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65335779/how-the-use-threads-in-groovy-to-iterate-0-4-million-records/65390302#comment115512240_65335779), in real work you would be using SQL to do a mass update of rows. In contrast, looping object by object in Java to update row by row in the database would be inordinately slow compared to a simple `UPDATE…` in SQL.

But for the sake of exploration, we will ignore this fact, and proceed with your Question.

## Trying virtual threads with *Project Loom*

The correct [Answer by Matias Bjarland](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65336895/642706) inspired me to try similar code using the [Project Loom](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/loom/Main) technology coming to Java. Project Loom brings virtual threads ([fibers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_(computer_science))) for faster concurrency with simpler coding.

Project Loom is still in the experimental stage, but is seeking feedback from the Java community. Special builds of early-access Java 16 with Project Loom technology built-in are [available now](http://jdk.java.net/loom/) for the Linux/Mac/Windows OSes.

My code here uses Java syntax, as I do not know Groovy.

I want to try similar code to the other Answer, creating a simple `Employee` with a a single member field `quantity`. And with an `EmployeeService` offering a `save` method that simulates writing to a database by merely sleeping a full second.

One major feature of Project Loom is that blocking a thread, and switching to work on another thread, now becomes very cheap. So many of the tricks and techniques used in writing Java code to avoid expensive blocking became unnecessary. So the batching seen in the other Answer should not be needed when using virtual threads. So the code below simply loops all half million `Employee` objects, and creates a new `Runnable` object for each one. As each of the new half-million `Runnable` objects are instantiated, they are submitted to an executor service.

We run this code twice, using either of two kinds of executor services. One is the conventional type using platform/kernel threads used for many years in Java before Project Loom, specifically, the executor service backed by a fixed thread pool. The other kind is the new executor service offered in Project Loom for virtual threads.

- [Executors.newFixedThreadPool( int countThreads )](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/loom/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int))
- [Executors.newVirtualThreadExecutor()](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/loom/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newVirtualThreadExecutor())

### Code

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class HalfMillion
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        HalfMillion app = new HalfMillion();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "java.runtime.version " + System.getProperty( "java.runtime.version" ) );
        System.out.println( "INFO - `demo` method starting. " + Instant.now() );
        // Populate data.
        List < Employee > employees = IntStream.rangeClosed( 1 , 500_000 ).mapToObj( i -> new Employee() ).collect( Collectors.toList() );

        // Submit task (updating field in each object) to an executor service.
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        EmployeeService employeeService = new EmployeeService();
        try (
                //ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 5 ) ;  // 5 of 6 real cores, no hyper-threading.
                ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadExecutor() ;
        )
        {
            employees
                    .stream()
                    .forEach(
                            employee -> {
                                executorService.submit(
                                        new Runnable()
                                        {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run ( )
                                            {
                                                employee.quantity = 8;
                                                employeeService.save( employee );
                                            }
                                        }
                                );
                            }
                    );
        }
        // With Project Loom, the code blocks here until all submitted tasks have finished.
        Duration duration = Duration.ofNanos( System.nanoTime() - start );

        // Report.
        System.out.println( "INFO - Done running demo for " + employees.size() + " employees taking " + duration + " to finish at " + Instant.now() );
    }


    class Employee
    {
        int quantity;

        @Override
        public String toString ( )
        {
            return "Employee{ " +
                    "quantity=" + quantity +
                    " }";
        }
    }

    class EmployeeService
    {
        public void save ( Employee employee )
        {
            //System.out.println( "TRACE - An `EmployeeService` is doing `save` on an employee." );
            try {Thread.sleep( Duration.ofSeconds( 1 ) );} catch ( InterruptedException e ) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }
}
```

### Results

I ran that code on a Mac mini (2018) with 3 GHz Intel Core i5 processor having 6 real cores and no hyper-threading, with 32 GB 2667 MHz DDR4 memory, and running macOS Mojave 10.14.6.

#### Using the new virtual threads of Project Loom

Using `Executors.newVirtualThreadExecutor()` takes **under 5 seconds**.

```
java.runtime.version 16-loom+9-316
INFO - `demo` method starting. 2020-12-21T09:20:36.273351Z
INFO - Done running demo for 500000 employees taking PT4.517136095S to finish at 2020-12-21T09:20:40.885315Z
```

If I enabled the `println` line within the `save` method, it took 15 seconds.

#### Using a fixed pool of 5 conventional platform/kernel threads

Using `Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 5 )` takes … well, *much longer. Over a day instead of seconds: 27 hours.

```
java.runtime.version 16-loom+9-316
INFO - `demo` method starting. 2020-12-21T09:32:07.173561Z
INFO - Done running demo for 500000 employees taking PT27H58M18.930703698S to finish at 2020-12-22T13:30:28.813345Z
```

#### Conclusion

Well I’m not sure I can draw a conclusion here.

The results for the conventional thread pool make sense. Remember that each Java thread maps to a kernel thread in the host OS. If we are sleeping one second per employee object, as we saturate 5 cores there will mostly be 5 threads sleeping most of the time. This means the total duration should be at least a hundred thousand seconds.

The results for virtual threads on Project Loom are not believable. The command to sleep the current thread seems to ignored when using virtual threads. But I am not certain; perhaps my five physical cores on this Mac were able to be sleeping simultaneously about a hundred thousand threads each?

Please post criticisms if you find fault with my code or approach. I am not an expert on threading and concurrency.

Comment: I did a similar test using groovy a while back. I did one million sleep 500ms in my test in 10 seconds using the virtual thread executor. Essentially ignoring context switching etc this is 50k concurrent threads. Agree, it is a quantum leap, but it is believable since this is the whole point of the new fibers implementation and in loom, one thread no longer maps to one os thread, they are light weight and managed by the jvm. A good video from one of the people involved in implementing loom: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fOEPEXTpbJA&feature=emb_logo.